# display data in codenameoone using table

Tags: json, codenameone

am making a mobile app using codenameone and i want to display the data from database which i get the following json response using asp.net api

```
{
  "FullNames": "sample string 1",
  "PhoneNumber": "sample string 2",
  "Date": "sample string 3",
  "PickupPoint": "sample string 4",
  "Destination": "sample string 5",
  "Reason": "sample string 6",
  "Time": "sample string 7",
  "Booking": "sample string 8"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the JSON using Properties or the JSON parser. Both are supported by the `Rest` API which returns a map or a `PropertyBusinessObject` respectively.

The `Table` is the simple part. You can create it with the [Table](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/table/Table.html) class.

A super trivial implementation would look something like:

```java
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
    new String[] {"Name", "Value"},
    new Object[][] {
        { "Full Name", UserInfo.fullName.get() },
        { "Phone Number", UserInfo.phoneNumber.get() },
        ...
    }
) {
    public boolean isEditable(int row, int column) { return column == 1; }
};
Table table = new Table(model);
Form f = new Form("My Table", new BorderLayout());
f.add(CENTER, table);
f.show();
```

Now notice that we have an automatic UI option that generates a table of business objects for you: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/table-property-mapping.html

But this works for a list of business object, not for an individual object.